# Reference Newtonsoft.Json in a Azure function

Tags: json, azure, azure-functions

I want to use Newtonsoft.Json in my Azure function but if i use #r Newtonsoft.Json, as defined in documentation I get the error "Internal Server Error 500". What do I do wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use

```
#r "NewtonSoft.Json"
```

Including the quotes!

Sander